# Why return value optimization does not work when return ()

Tags: c++, c++11

My code is as follows. Why () makes RVO fail?

```
A fn() {
    A a{};
    return (a); // move constructor of class A works
    return a;   // RVO works
}

int main() {
    A a = fn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: RVO requires a prvalue. Neither of the two expressions is a prvalue. The second expression is NRVO, which is at the compiler's discretion. A more interesting question is whether the first expression qualifies for NRVO. Don't know.

Comment: The fact you use parenthesis lead to a reference. That's why it does not work :).

Comment: Reference for [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to illustrate Sam's comment.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier that is not true; both versions are lvalues of type `A`

Comment: @cosimoth: which compiler do you use?

Comment: Hopefully, this problem will be gone in C++23: wg21.link/p2025

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is NRVO, not RVO.

Here is the rule which allows NRVO (class.copy/31):

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, **when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object** (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv- unqualiﬁed type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

As you can see, in the case of `(a)`, the expression is not a name (because of the added parenthesis), so NRVO is not allowed.

Comment: You might want to add that the rule for automatic move does however allow parentheses around the name, which is why the move constructor, not the copy constructor, is still used. (See next paragraph in the standard.)

Comment: @walnut: Hmm, I'm not sure that that's the paragraph, as it starts with "When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
object is a function parameter, ...". Yes it has a note about the "general" case later, but I think the normative text is somewhere else about this (I don't have the time to check for this now, but I'll do this later).

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the C++17 document, where parentheses are specifically allowed. But then OP's compiler is actually wrong to use the move constructor as they indicate.

Comment: It was changed in C++14 with [CWG issue 1579](https://wg21.link/cwg1579). If OP is really compiling as C++11, then there should be a copy constructor call, not a move constructor call with the parentheses.

Comment: @walnut resolution of Defects is considered retroactive

Comment: @M.M All of them to all versions of C++? I thought there is different meaning to the "Status" field which says "C++14" in this case. Some of the resolutions are breaking changes that I don't believe are intended to apply to earlier versions, for example [issue 903](https://wg21.link/cwg903).

Comment: @walnut the CWG 1579 was raised in 2012 and moved to DR before C++14 published (IDK any more detail)

Comment: @walnut: The funny thing is, gcc uses NRVO for `return (f)` in C++11 mode. But it doesn't use NRVO in C++14/17 mode (uses move constructor instead). Clang always uses NRVO for `return (f)` (no matter of C++11/14/17).